# Starting Protractor tool throws some error first, But runs fine after that

Tags: selenium, protractor

```
    E:\Work\Test>grunt test-e2e
    Running "protractor_webdriver:start" (protractor_webdriver) task
    Starting Selenium server
    Started Selenium server: http://127.0.0.1:4444

    Running "protractor:start" (protractor) task
    webdriver-manager path: E:\Work\Test\node_modules\protractor\bin\webdriver-manager
    [11:36:31] I/update - chromedriver: file exists E:\Work\Test\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chromedriver_2.26win32.zip
    [11:36:31] I/update - chromedriver: unzipping chromedriver_2.26win32.zip
    E:\Work\Test\node_modules\q\q.js:155
                    throw e;
                    ^

    Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'E:\Work\Test\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chromedriver.exe' -> 'E:\Work\Test\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chromedriver_2.26.exe'
        at Error (native)
        at Object.fs.renameSync (fs.js:810:18)
        at unzip (E:\Work\Test\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\built\lib\cmds\update.js:210:8)
        at E:\Work\Test\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\built\lib\cmds\update.js:180:13
        at _fulfilled (E:\Work\Test\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
        at self.promiseDispatch.done (E:\Work\Test\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30)
        at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (E:\Work\Test\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
        at E:\Work\Test\node_modules\q\q.js:604:44
        at runSingle (E:\Work\Test\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
        at flush (E:\Work\Test\node_modules\q\q.js:125:13)
    [11:36:41] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
    [11:36:41] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
    Jasmine started
    [656:2544:0930/113649.269:ERROR:shader_disk_cache.cc(237)] Failed to create shader cache entry: -2
    [656:2544:0930/113707.323:ERROR:shader_disk_cache.cc(237)] Failed to create shader cache entry: -2
    [656:2544:0930/113707.431:ERROR:service_manager.cc(156)] Connection InterfaceProviderSpec prevented service: content_plugin from binding interface: memory_instrumentation::mojom::Coordinator exposed by: content_browser

  0. Test App Login Module
    √ module 0.1 should Login


  33. Existing a contact tile.
    √ Existing a contact

Executed 2 of 2 specs SUCCESS in 1 min 22 secs.
[12:06:18] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[12:06:18] I/launcher - chrome #01 passed

E:\Work\Test>
```

I am using grunt task runner with protractor testing tool. I have two questions.

1. When I run test, It gives the above error. `(Error before Jasmine started.)`, but after that all the test-suites run fine as expected. So what is this error means?
2. I am using `directConnect:true` in my conf.js file. Why it shows in console like-

Starting Selenium server

Started Selenium server: http://127.0.0.1:4444

3. What is the below error suppose to mean?

> ```
> Jasmine started
> [656:2544:0930/113649.269:ERROR:shader_disk_cache.cc(237)] Failed to create shader cache entry: -2
> [656:2544:0930/113707.323:ERROR:shader_disk_cache.cc(237)] Failed to create shader cache entry: -2
> [656:2544:0930/113707.431:ERROR:service_manager.cc(156)] Connection InterfaceProviderSpec prevented service: content_plugin
> ```
>
> from binding interface: memory_instrumentation::mojom::Coordinator
>   exposed by: content_browser

**UPDATE**

this is my Package.json File

```
{
  "name": "E2E-Test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Vikash.777",
  "description": "Grunt File Configuration",
  "dependencies": {
    "fs-extra": "^4.0.1",
    "grunt": "~0.4.4",
    "grunt-protractor-runner": "^4.0.0",
    "grunt-protractor-webdriver": "^0.2.5",
    "grunt-simple-mocha": "^0.4.1",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.5.2",
    "jasmine-reporters": "^2.2.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.1.0",
    "jasmine2-protractor-utils": "^1.3.0",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.2",
    "protractor-html-reporter": "^1.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt-open": "^0.2.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Post your `package.json` as well as js config for protractor

Comment: I have posted my package.json file.                                                              [Tarun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2830850/tarun-lalwani)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So below are the issues you have. You have a task `test-e2e` which initiates `protractor:start` which is running `webdriver-manager update` and `webdriver-manager start`

Now this will download the chromedriver. and try to move to named version.

```
E:\Work\Test\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chromedriver.exe' -> 'E:\Work\Test\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chromedriver_2.26.exe
```

And another process is already running which makes the move impossible. So you need to kill all existing `chromedriver.exe`. Also the start task may be launching the selenium grid also which is not needed in your case. What you should do is only let protractor control the launch. Remove any tasks that are executing webdriver manager by itself

Comment: Can we syncronize these tasks, like first webdriver-manager update, then webdriver-manager start?

Comment: Yes that would be there in your grunt file.  See https://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks